# JDBC Connection timed out for SQL server on AWS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, jdbc, amazon-ec2

I have a SQL server running on Amazon cloud. I have a security group attached to the instance with inbound ports opened for everybody. Here is the rules configuration looks like [image: this]

My JDBC connection string looks like this.

```
jdbc:sqlserver://x.x.x.x;databasename=CDS_NY
```

I'm using the publicIP of the instance here. My java client fails to establish connection with below error. What am I doing wrong here?

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host x.x.x.x, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:241)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2243)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:491)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1309)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at com.wilhelmina.reports.Main.getConnection(Main.java:54)
    at com.wilhelmina.reports.Main.main(Main.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Comment: Srini, are you behind a firewall? Port 1433 might be blocked on the firewall. Can you get to the server from an other machine?

Comment: @mauroneto I have not explicitly enable firewall on the windows instance that I started on EC2. If the firewall is supposed to be enabled by default I guess I have to disable it. My windows knowledge is limited !!.

Comment: Take a look on the control panel (Start > Control Panel) and make sure its off, just to be safe